# Is the sum of two exponential distributed random no. is also exponential random number?

Tags: statistics, exponential-sum

I am working on statistics after long time. Struggling with the basics.

Is the sum of two exponential distributed random no. is also exponential random number?

Comment: The "sum" operation for exponential variables is actually the maximum: if you have independent exponentials with means $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ then their maximum is exponential with mean $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. Similarly the minimum is exponential with mean satisfying $\frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$ (the frequencies add rather than the times). It is no coincidence that these formulas are identical to the effective resistance of two resistors in series and parallel respectively. :)

Comment: The intuitive reason that the *sum* is not exponential is because the situation modeled by the sum is one where you have to wait for the first event to occur before you can even start waiting for the second event to occur. This model has memory: it "knows" at any given time whether the first event has already occurred or not. Exponential variables cannot have memory in this sense. (In fact, exponential variables are the only nonnegative continuous variables which have no memory in this sense.)

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and each have the same Exponential distribution, then $Y\equiv X_1+\cdots+X_n$ has a Gamma distribution.

I don't mention the specific parameters in the Exponential and Gamma distributions because different texts use different parameterizations of these distributions.